# Extending axes to encompass all data in R

Tags: r

I feel like this is a very basic question but I have spent a lot of time looking for an answer and haven't found one. So, if this is answered somewhere else I would love to be redirected rather than downvoted, please.

Anyway, my problem is that when I graph in R, often the y-axis will fail to extend to the end of my data. A sample graphic is below, where you can see that it would be better for the axis to go all the way to 30 rather than 20. However, submitting ylim = c(0,30) doesn't do anything and I cannot think of or find another command that would do the trick?

[image]

Here is a reproducible example. If ylim usually works then I am assuming something is breaking because of the aesthetic changes I've made?

```
set.seed(1)
x<-runif(1:1000, min=1, max=10)
hist(x, breaks=100, main=NA, axes=F, xlab = NA,  ylab = NA)

axis(side = 1, tck= -.01, labels=NA)
axis(side = 2, tck=-.01, labels=NA)
axis(side = 1, lwd=0, line= -.4, cex.axis=1.4)
axis(side = 2, lwd=0, line=-.4, las=1, cex.axis=1.4)
mtext(side = 1, "Percent pathogenic bacteria", line = 2.5, cex=1.8)
mtext(side = 2, "Frequency", line = 2.5, cex=1.8)
```

Comment: It would help if you'd supply a reproducible example of your problem since, as @user20650 notes, the `ylim` argument should work (as in: `x <- runif(n=800); hist(x, breaks=40, ylim=c(0,30))`).

Comment: Re your edit; you have not added ylim to your hist call. After adding this it works for me

Comment: Gah! I knew it was something stupid I was overlooking. I kept putting it into every part of the axis calls and testing it out to no avail, it never occurred to me it would go in hist. And I wasn't confident it was the right command anyway. 

It's frightening how much time I've wasted on this, so thank you for your help. I feel like this doesn't add much to the community though, would this be a good thing to delete?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ylim` to specify the y axis range:

```
set.seed(3) 
f <- function(y, ...) 
  hist(y, breaks=20, ...)
ylim <- range(pretty(ceiling(f(y <- rchisq(1000, 3), plot=FALSE)$counts/10)*10))
f(y, ylim=ylim) # versus f(y)
```

[image]